# How to develop a CRM system

Tags: php, asp.net, jsp

I need to develop a CRM system within 2 months recently. But I'm still a student and have no experience in developing such a complex system. I did alot of researches on how to develop a CRM system, but I face some problems on designing the system.

The problems that I faced are:

1. Does a CRM system use any framework for development? (eg: DooPHP, Yii, Zend, and so on)
2. How to ensure the system is secure? (use OpenSSL?)
3. What are the non-functionality that I need to bear in mind?

For your guys information, the CRM that I gonna develop is for a small company use. However, I hope that the system is fast in response and secure, as this is what we want when using a web application. It is ok for me to use PHP, JSP or ASP.Net.

If anyone developed the similar system before, kindly share your experience with us. If possible, share your code here.

Thanks...

Comment: Look for any open source that may get you some ideas

Comment: Depending on your requirements (business & cost) you may want to look into one of the many CRM solutions out there, Salesforce.com offers a very flexible developer environment that is based on the CRM idea. There are also some open source ones out there with many features such as SugarCRM. Not to dissuade you from rolling your own solution, but part of the development process is determining if there is already something out there that does what you need.

Comment: I would recommend Asp.NET for a better code-behind structure and it is really fast.

Answer (score 4):

A CRM system can be quite complex. In fact, I worked on a custom CRM system and the codebase is literally by far greater than 100000 lines of code. Two months can be challenging depending on what functionality you'll need.

Using a framework is up to you. I once tested XAF from DevExpress which aim to help at classic CRM/LOB tasks unless some details get not too complex. OpenSSL is only an implementation, but if the data should be safe, then one key point would be using SSL along with good authentication and authorization. Number three: that depends. A good logging framework is always worse the work.

Have you considered using an open CRM system to start over with? There is [jfire](http://www.jfire.net/) or [vTiger](http://www.vtiger.de/en) for example.

Comment: Actually, I need to develop the core system for the CRM first. But I worry that if using framework, it will cause the server's response become slower. Yes, I did consider open source CRM, but is it suitable to be modified and sold?

Comment: Open Source CRM might probably not being sold as proprietary systems. Even a fork would probably be required to be open source. What might be possible is to develop modules / addins that can be sold or just selling the service to customize the CRM system. But all that has to be clarified by reading and understanding the CRM system's license.

Answer (score 3):

Your CRM should be easy to implement but don't take anything for granted. You will have a chance to learn a lot of things in terms of language features and technology when developing such software. If you are looking forward to it, not a problem, you can easily do it.

As far as your questions.

1. CRM Does not have to use any framework. If you are familiar with one, good for you. You can use it to your advantage and it *will* be helpful.
2. Stick with common security features that are used in any language, particularly the language that you use. Do not be obsessed with it. You will learn a few things as you go.
3. No sure about the non-functionality. But be careful to stick to the *features* only. Do not overdo things that will increase complexity and the time it will require to complete. Implement what is asked for.

Any language will do. I personally like PHP. ASP.NET can be quite challenging. There are a lot of things that you think will work and they are quite pain to implement (if you are not a guru already). So depending on your experience and if you worked with any software development before, it is not daunting but to be honest, you must have some somewhere development experience. There is nothing strange in it.

Make sure you are well familiar with basic data types such as float, double etc. You can introduce big errors if you use them wrong.

Comment: Yup, one of the reason that I want to develop the system is, I would like to learn something new for me. Last time, I used codeigniter to develop the CRM system (I just continue the development that someone left it). However, this time, I would like to a completely new and stable one.

Comment: It seems like you are doing it for your own self? Well in that case my advice would be stick with your preferred language, I'd prefer PHP. If you choose ASP.NET, there is steep learning curve involved and there are *too* many things involved that you have to learn first. That will take you definitely longer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to understand one system is to review some open source projects:

http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/
http://www.opencrx.org/

And much more :

http://www.focus.com/briefs/top-10-open-source-crm-solutions/